# How to use a local image instead of a URL to an image via glide?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

In this code as I understand it downloads the image from url and it takes time, so it shows up with a delay. I think this delay would be gone if I use a local image. How can I use a local image instead of the downloaded image?

```
private fun updateView() {
        imageViewBackground.post {
            ThreadUtil.startThread {
                val imageUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tff-sample.appspot.com/o/TeacherPhoto%2FteacherPhoto.jpg?alt=media&token=7d462beb-8c6d-4467-9139-1de0f75b8563"
                val futureTarget: FutureTarget<Bitmap> = Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(imageUrl)
                .submit (imageViewBackground.width, imageViewBackground.height)
                val bitmap = futureTarget.get()

                ThreadUtil.startUIThread(delayMillis = 0) {
                    imageViewBackground.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

                    frameLayoutInputArea.post {

                        var cropBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageViewBackground.width, imageViewBackground.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
                        val canvas = Canvas(cropBitmap)
                        imageViewBackground.draw(canvas)

                        cropBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cropBitmap, frameLayoutInputArea.x.toInt(), frameLayoutInputArea.y.toInt(), frameLayoutInputArea.width, frameLayoutInputArea.height)

                        imageViewBlur.setImageBitmap(BitmapUtil.blurBitmap(this, cropBitmap))

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Glide has several `load` functions, including ones that take [a `File`](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/400/com/bumptech/glide/RequestBuilder.html#load-java.io.File-), [a `Uri`](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/400/com/bumptech/glide/RequestBuilder.html#load-android.net.Uri-) or [an `Integer` resource ID](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/400/com/bumptech/glide/RequestBuilder.html#load-java.lang.Integer-). So however you're storing your local image, there's a function you can just plug it into

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use Glide and you want to store it so that it will be easily accessible after first load, then you can consider using Glide's cache strategies (See https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html).

If you want to use a local image (which I am assuming you don't want to use Glide at all), then you can simply download that image and put it inside `res/drawable` folder and use it like `imageViewBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.downloaded_image)`.

Comment: I willl check that way, thank you. I need to check because user still experience the delayed appearence of the background image.